# how can i remove null section and combine into one in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT A_NAME,
ROUND(CASE
WHEN M_TYPE_CODE = 001
THEN AVG(A_PRICE)
END) AS A,
ROUND(CASE
WHEN M_TYPE_CODE = 002
THEN AVG(A_PRICE)
END) AS B
FROM PRICE
GROUP BY A_NAME, M_TYPE_CODE;
```

When I use this the result is

```
A_NAME   ㅣ   A   ㅣ    B   ㅣ
Apple    ㅣ(null) ㅣ  3313  ㅣ
Apple    ㅣ 3000  ㅣ (null) ㅣ
Grape    ㅣ(null) ㅣ  5020  ㅣ
Grape    ㅣ 3140  ㅣ (null) ㅣ
...
```

so I thought it would group A_NAME into one, but instead ii came out to two different row with null how can i remove null and combine into one?

[image: another error]

Comment: remove the group by M_Type_Code; and the avg looks to be poorly placed. should be outside the case.  i'm not sure if you're trying to avg all records or just the non-null ones...

Comment: Part of the issue is that the fact that there can be one or more type codes which your case statement references would indicate that it's likely they are used and will cause multiple lines.  The easiest way to deal with this is to wrap it in a "select a_name, max(a) as a, max(b) as b from [your query] group by a_name.

Comment: You need to tag your question correctly. You used the mysql tag, but you are using Oracle. They are different, and have different functions. Please update your question and use the correct tag.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if the AVG and coalese will give you the desired results though.

```
SELECT A_NAME
     , ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN M_TYPE_CODE = '001' THEN coalesce(A_PRICE,0) END)) AS A
     , ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN M_TYPE_CODE = '002' THEN coalesce(A_PRICE,0) END)) AS B
FROM PRICE
GROUP BY A_NAME;
```

or maybe this depending on what you're trying to accomplish for avg.

```
SELECT A_NAME
     , ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN M_TYPE_CODE = '001' THEN A_PRICE END)) AS A
     , ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN M_TYPE_CODE = '002' THEN A_PRICE END)) AS B
FROM PRICE
GROUP BY A_NAME;
```

Comment: this works but the number is different probably because of average?

Comment: It's likely the coalesce in case of the average.  By coalescing to 0 i'm effecting the denominator of the average.  Perhaps you don't want that so remove the coalesce around A_PRICE

Answer (score 0):

You are getting two lines per A_NAME because the group by also uses the M_TYPE_CODE, but you didn't include that column in the column list. Try this instead:

```
SELECT A_NAME,
    AVG(IF(`M_TYPE_CODE` = '001',A_PRICE,NULL)) AS `A`,
    AVG(IF(`M_TYPE_CODE` = '002',A_PRICE,NULL)) AS `B`
FROM PRICE
GROUP BY A_NAME;
```

Without the back tics in case it is a language setting issue:

```
SELECT A_NAME,
    AVG(IF(M_TYPE_CODE = '001',A_PRICE,NULL)) AS A,
    AVG(IF(M_TYPE_CODE = '002',A_PRICE,NULL)) AS B
FROM PRICE
GROUP BY A_NAME;
```

Comment: hmm the error says 'not a single-group group function'

Comment: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
----------------------------------------------------
SELECT A_NAME,
    AVG(IF('M0_TYPE_CODE' = '001',A_PRICE,NULL)) AS `A`,
    AVG(IF('M_TYPE_CODE' = '002',A_PRICE,NULL)) AS `B`
FROM PRICE
GROUP BY A_NAME

Comment: hmm...i really appreciate the help but still got error

Comment: it says missing right parenthesis..that's all----------------i posted two images above don't bother about the language image '2' is the basic table and '1'is the result im having trouble right now it shows one item into two different row and your code seems to make error

Comment: In a comment just above, it shows single quotes around M_TYPE_CODE, they should be backtics. Did you edit the code above and change any of the quote characters? Or any other characters?

Comment: yes all i changed from your code is single quotes but that error occurs other than that i didn't touch anything

Comment: Single quotes are for values, backtics are for column and table names. Don't change them.

Comment: ok then the error message says 'invalid character' didn't touch any code of yours

Comment: It should indicate where the invalid character is. Care to share that info?

Comment: Take a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/000437/1/0) You may have an issue due to language settings. You might try it again without any back tics.

Comment: oh it's weird...I tried with cmd and still the same error occured---I posted error image again above

Comment: You tagged your question as mysql, but you are using Oracle. They have different syntax and functions.